# Ruby on Rails namespace issue with iCalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, conflict, icalendar

i'm developing a calendar webapp for my company using ruby 1.8.7 and
rails 2.3.8.  naturally there are RoR models named "Calendar" and "Event".

in order to send calendar events to other apps (microsoft outlook &
lotus notes) i'm integrating with the iCalendar standard & ruby
library.  http://icalendar.rubyforge.org/
but this library contains classes called "Calendar" and
"Event"

now my app is getting lotta errors like this when it tries to use
activerecord find - @calendar = Calendar.find(id) :

NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for **Icalendar::Calendar:Class**):
 app/controllers/foos_controller.rb:184:in`sendEmailDialogForm'
 C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'

is there some way to do:

@calendar = ActiveRecord::Base.Calendar.find(id) ??

```
  or
```

@calendar = appname.Calendar.find(id)

```
  or
```

@calendar =  this.Calendar.find(id)

lazily trying to avoid using a module to specify a namespace or to rename my
models.

Comment: Renaming your models might be the easiest thing to do. Otherwise you will hit a lot of problems later, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking you have an `include Icalendar` somewhere.  Try pulling that out & making your calls to that library using `Icalendar::Calendar.new(...)`.  This should take care of the namespace conflicts.

Comment: commented out the include                                       #include Icalendar                                                  and then                                                       @calendar = Icalendar::Calendar.new